# How do I artificially increase the latency for a device in my network?

Tags: networking, internet-connection, latency

I want to test how ping would affect my gameplay on Call of Duty on PS4 and was wondering if there was a way to add about 100ms latency to my PS4's network connection?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is there any way of adding about 100ms ping to ones connection?

Comment: do you want to ping a particular machine every 100ms?

Comment: Depends. What network hardware do you have?

Comment: Router and modem

Comment: What practical use would this test be? You cannot influence your ping to an online game in any positive manner other than move closer to where the servers are hosted. Higher ping will make the game feel 'laggy'. If it's a shoot em up against other online players, you'll lose more often.

Comment: Well I just wanted to test it

Answer (score 1):

The simplest mechanism is to route all the traffic through a secondary box that is running, for example, Linux, where you have access to tools such as [tc](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/intro.html) which allow you to manipulate the traffic in many ways.

Getting the PS4 to route the traffic is a matter of statically configuring the route to go through that device (I'm on a phone so detailing how to accomplish that is a matter of googling).

You can introduce delays, randomized packet loss, maximum bandwidth allocations; all of which can be used to simulate many network conditions.

Comment: Thank you I will look to google for solutions to routing traffic